# Hide UIImageView in for with viewWithTag

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, tags

I have 5 `UIImageView`s with tags 100, 101, 102, 103, 104.

I want to make them appear when the user validates an exercise. So if 1 exercise is validated the `UIImageView` with the tag 100 will appear. If 2 exercices are validate, then both `UIImageView` with tags 100 and 101 will appear, etc. I tried the code below, but only one image appears. Why? How can I fix this?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

    UIImageView *coin = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100+j];

    NSLog(@"coin.x: %f, coin.y: %f", coin.frame.origin.x, coin.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"cointag = %d", coin.tag);
    if (j < library.themesCompleted)
    {
        NSLog(@"HIDDEN = NO");
        coin.hidden = NO;        
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"HIDDEN = YES");
        coin.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

This appears in the logs:

```
2012-06-27 18:24:06.463 test[4499:1da07] coin.x: 77.000000, coin.y: 1.000000
2012-06-27 18:24:06.463 test[4499:1da07] cointag = 100
2012-06-27 18:24:06.463 test[4499:1da07] HIDDEN = NO
2012-06-27 18:24:06.464 test[4499:1da07] coin.x: 92.000000, coin.y: 1.000000
2012-06-27 18:24:06.464 test[4499:1da07] cointag = 101
2012-06-27 18:24:06.464 test[4499:1da07] HIDDEN = NO
2012-06-27 18:24:06.464 test[4499:1da07] coin.x: 107.000000, coin.y: 2.000000
2012-06-27 18:24:06.465 test[4499:1da07] cointag = 102
2012-06-27 18:24:06.465 test[4499:1da07] HIDDEN = YES
2012-06-27 18:24:06.465 test[4499:1da07] coin.x: 122.000000, coin.y: 1.000000
2012-06-27 18:24:06.465 test[4499:1da07] cointag = 103
2012-06-27 18:24:06.466 test[4499:1da07] HIDDEN = YES
2012-06-27 18:24:06.466 test[4499:1da07] coin.x: 136.000000, coin.y: 1.000000
2012-06-27 18:24:06.466 test[4499:1da07] cointag = 104
2012-06-27 18:24:06.466 test[4499:1da07] HIDDEN = YES
```

Comment: Instead of using (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100+j], try renaming your image files instead of using tags and use [UIImage image named:@"Imagename.png"]. I'm not sure if it's exactly what your looking for, but it could be a little bit easier?

Comment: The 5 UIViewImage are using the same .png :s

Comment: Wait, so what's different about them?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", coin); please. This will output the object ID and it's frame, yo confirm if you have set your tags correctly.